# Dropdown with modules are empty in IIS web sever

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I need to add WSFederationAuthenticationModule module into web application, so i go to IIS -> select my web project -> go to Modules -> and click Add Managed Module and see this

[image]

But on the production server i don't see anything just empty list:

[image]